# Вопрос по перегрузке оператора в ООП С++

Tags: c++, ооп, перегрузка-операторов

Есть такой код

```
class CustomFoo {
 
   virtual void do_stuff()=0;
};

class Foo: CustomFoo {
   
    void do_staff() {....} final;
};


class FooWrapper {

  vector<CustomFoo*> foos;
  
  CustomFoo* operator->() {return foo[0];}
};


void main(){

  FooWrapper wrapper;
  wrapper.foos.push_back(new Foo());
  wrapper->do_staff();
}
```

Код компилируется но не работает
Завершается ошибкой (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)
Как это можно заставить работать, т.е. при использовании оператора -> вызывать соответствующую функцию из Foo.
Спасибо.

Comment: Читаем: `SIGSEGV (от англ. signal и segmentation violation) — сигнал, используемый в POSIX-системах, посылаемый процессу при ошибках сегментации — отказах страниц и других попытках обращения к несуществующей области памяти или при обращениях с нарушением прав доступа. `

Comment: Пример кода воспроизводимый пожалуйста, этот не компилируется.  https://ideone.com/jbKZQ0

Comment: [Компилируется?](https://ideone.com/eMtP2c)

Answer (score 0):

Если довести ваш код до *компилируемого* состояния, то [все работает](https://ideone.com/xycWzJ):

```
class CustomFoo {
public:
    virtual void do_staff()=0;
};

class Foo: public CustomFoo {
public:
    void do_staff() override { cout << "do_staff()\n"; };
};


class FooWrapper {
public:
    vector<CustomFoo*> foos;
    CustomFoo* operator->() {return foos[0];}
};


int main(){

    FooWrapper wrapper;
    wrapper.foos.push_back(new Foo());
    wrapper->do_staff();
}
```

Comment: А виртуального деструктора в базовом классе нет - это чтобы можно было "героически" побороть очередной сегфолт, когда deletе начнёт удалять объекты производного класса через указатель на базовый? )

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл Давайте решать проблемы по мере их поступления :) Вам кто-то мешал написать верный ответ, а не просто брошенное свысока "не компилируется"? Вы считаете ответ неверным — отлично! Ставите минус, поясняете, почему, *и пишете правильный ответ*.

Comment: Не "не компилируется", а "Компилируется?". Ты не просто довёл код до компилируемого состояния, а умышленно добавил бомбу замедленного действия. Вот когда она оторвёт ноги по самую шею вот тогда и поговорим? ) "минус, поясняете, почему, и пишете" Может тебе еще рождественские открытки каждый год отправлять? )) Теперь отчетливо понятно отчего твои ответы минусуют без комментариев )))

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл лучше вашу энергию направить в сторону Комитета по стандартизации и разработчиков компиляторов - почему они не позаботились о детекте очевидно ошибочной ситуации - когда есть класс с абстрактными методами, нужно требовать наличия виртуального деструктора.